# Extended InstanceContext Initialize method never fires

Tags: c#, wcf, extension-methods

I have taken over a project that was build from suggestions in this [Dan Rigsby's article](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/24/extending-wcf-instancecontext-to-store-custom-state/)

But for some reason the **Initalize** method in the class that inherit *IInstanceContextIntializer* is never fired where as the constructor is. I'll need the Initialize to fire so the extension can be added to the InstanceContext.

Anyone experienced this and have a possible solution or suggestions?

Much appreciated

Partial code blocks:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPSRestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "blockActivityTrans", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    transAckResponseData PostBlockActivity(blockActivityData blockactivitydata);
    ...
}
```

---

```
[ESBAPICreation]
    public class PSRestService : IPSRestService
    {
    ...
            public transAckResponseData PostBlockActivity(blockActivityData blockactivitydata)
        {
            OutgoingWebResponseContext outResponse = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
            IncomingWebRequestContext inRequest = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;
            bool isNew;
            transAckResponseData trans = PSDB.PutBlockActivity(blockactivitydata, out isNew);

            return trans;
        }
    ...}
```

---

```
public class PSRestServiceFactory : ServiceHostFactoryBase
{
    public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string service, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
    // The service parameter is ignored here because we know our service.
        PSRestServiceHost serviceHost = new PSRestServiceHost(typeof(PSRestService), baseAddresses);

        serviceHost.Opening += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Opening);
        serviceHost.Opened += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Opened);
        serviceHost.Closing += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Closing);
        serviceHost.Closed += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Closed);
        serviceHost.Faulted += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Faulted);
        serviceHost.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived);

        return serviceHost;
    }

    void serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived(object sender, UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Log("Unknown Message Received");
    }

    void serviceHost_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Log("service faulted");
    }

    void serviceHost_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Log("service closed");
    }

    void serviceHost_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Log("service closing by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
    }

    void serviceHost_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Log("service opened by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
    }

    void serviceHost_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Logger.Log("service opening by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PSRestServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public PSRestServiceHost(Type t, Uri[] addresses) : base(t, addresses)
    {
        Logger.Log("PSRestServiceHost constructor");
    }
}
```

---

```
[DataContract]
public class PSESBAPIExtension : IExtension<InstanceContext>
{
    private ESBAPIManager _manager;

    [DataMember]
    public ESBAPIManager ESBAPIManager
    {
        get { return _manager; }
    }

    public PSESBAPIExtension(ESBAPIManager Manager)
    {
        Logger.Log("PSESBAPIExtension constructor called");
        _manager = Manager;
    }

    public void Attach(InstanceContext owner)
    {
    }

    public void Detach(InstanceContext owner)
    {
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PSESBAPIInitializer : IInstanceContextInitializer
{
    private static ESBAPIManager _manager = null;

    public PSESBAPIInitializer()
    {
        if (_manager == null)
        {
            _manager = new ESBAPIManager();
            Logger.Log("New instance of API manager initialized");
        }
    }

    public void Initialize(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        Logger.Log("Extension added to the instance context");

        instanceContext.Extensions.Add(new PSESBAPIExtension(_manager));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ESBAPICreationAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(
        ContractDescription contractDescription,
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(
        ContractDescription contractDescription,
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(
        ContractDescription contractDescription,
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.InstanceContextInitializers.Add(new PSESBAPIInitializer());
        Logger.Log("Instance context initializer added");
    }

    public void Validate(
        ContractDescription contractDescription,
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed something important in your description. I step by step changed Dan's code with your code blocks and `Initialize` is risen. Try to prepare sample and put it in any free file share.

Comment: I'm not sure what I missed in the description?

Comment: Me too ). But I changed Dan's code with your blocks and 'Initialize' is still risen.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll have to dig deeper when I get back from my 2 weeks vacation :) Hopefully it is a simple solution I somehow miss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your exact code, added some missing pieces9, and it worked out fine. The main difference is that I defined the endpoint in the factory itself (I imagined you did on web.config). I tried for both self and webhosted cases, and the initializer was added in all of them. The code is shown below. Compare with what you have, and the differences should tell you what is wrong.

**Selfhost:**

```
public class StackOverflow_10721469
{
    public class ESBAPICreationAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(
            ContractDescription contractDescription,
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
            BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(
            ContractDescription contractDescription,
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
            ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(
            ContractDescription contractDescription,
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
            DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.InstanceContextInitializers.Add(new PSESBAPIInitializer());
            Logger.Log("Instance context initializer added");
        }

        public void Validate(
            ContractDescription contractDescription,
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }
    public class PSESBAPIInitializer : IInstanceContextInitializer
    {
        private static ESBAPIManager _manager = null;

        public PSESBAPIInitializer()
        {
            if (_manager == null)
            {
                _manager = new ESBAPIManager();
                Logger.Log("New instance of API manager initialized");
            }
        }

        public void Initialize(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
        {
            Logger.Log("Extension added to the instance context");

            instanceContext.Extensions.Add(new PSESBAPIExtension(_manager));
        }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class PSESBAPIExtension : IExtension<InstanceContext>
    {
        private ESBAPIManager _manager;

        [DataMember]
        public ESBAPIManager ESBAPIManager
        {
            get { return _manager; }
        }

        public PSESBAPIExtension(ESBAPIManager Manager)
        {
            Logger.Log("PSESBAPIExtension constructor called");
            _manager = Manager;
        }

        public void Attach(InstanceContext owner)
        {
        }

        public void Detach(InstanceContext owner)
        {
        }
    }
    public class ESBAPIManager { }
    public class PSRestServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        public PSRestServiceHost(Type t, Uri[] addresses)
            : base(t, addresses)
        {
            Logger.Log("PSRestServiceHost constructor");
        }
    }
    public class PSRestServiceFactory : ServiceHostFactoryBase
    {
        public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string service, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            // The service parameter is ignored here because we know our service. 
            PSRestServiceHost serviceHost = new PSRestServiceHost(typeof(PSRestService), baseAddresses);

            serviceHost.Opening += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Opening);
            serviceHost.Opened += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Opened);
            serviceHost.Closing += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Closing);
            serviceHost.Closed += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Closed);
            serviceHost.Faulted += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Faulted);
            serviceHost.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived);

            return serviceHost;
        }

        void serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived(object sender, UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("Unknown Message Received");
        }

        void serviceHost_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service faulted");
        }

        void serviceHost_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service closed");
        }

        void serviceHost_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service closing by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
        }

        void serviceHost_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service opened by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
        }

        void serviceHost_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service opening by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPSRestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "blockActivityTrans", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        transAckResponseData PostBlockActivity(blockActivityData blockactivitydata);
    }
    [ESBAPICreation]
    public class PSRestService : IPSRestService
    {
        public transAckResponseData PostBlockActivity(blockActivityData blockactivitydata)
        {
            return new transAckResponseData();
        }
    }
    public class blockActivityData { }
    public class transAckResponseData { }
    public class Logger
    {
        public static void Log(string text, params object[] args)
        {
            if (args != null && args.Length > 0) text = string.Format(text, args);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHostFactoryBase factory = new PSRestServiceFactory();
        ServiceHost host = (ServiceHost)factory.CreateServiceHost("unused", new Uri[] { new Uri(baseAddress) });
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
        Console.WriteLine(c.UploadString(baseAddress + "/blockActivityTrans", "null"));

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

**Webhost**:

**File: StackOverflow_10721469.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="StackOverflow_10721469.PSRestService"
            CodeBehind="StackOverflow_10721469.svc.cs" 
            Factory="StackOverflow_10721469.PSRestServiceFactory" %>
```

**File: StackOverflow_10721469.svc.cs**

```
namespace StackOverflow_10721469
{
    public class ESBAPICreationAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(
            ContractDescription contractDescription,
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
            BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(
            ContractDescription contractDescription,
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
            ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(
            ContractDescription contractDescription,
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
            DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
            dispatchRuntime.InstanceContextInitializers.Add(new PSESBAPIInitializer());
            Logger.Log("Instance context initializer added");
        }

        public void Validate(
            ContractDescription contractDescription,
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }
    public class PSESBAPIInitializer : IInstanceContextInitializer
    {
        private static ESBAPIManager _manager = null;

        public PSESBAPIInitializer()
        {
            if (_manager == null)
            {
                _manager = new ESBAPIManager();
                Logger.Log("New instance of API manager initialized");
            }
        }

        public void Initialize(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
        {
            Logger.Log("Extension added to the instance context");

            instanceContext.Extensions.Add(new PSESBAPIExtension(_manager));
        }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class PSESBAPIExtension : IExtension<InstanceContext>
    {
        private ESBAPIManager _manager;

        [DataMember]
        public ESBAPIManager ESBAPIManager
        {
            get { return _manager; }
        }

        public PSESBAPIExtension(ESBAPIManager Manager)
        {
            Logger.Log("PSESBAPIExtension constructor called");
            _manager = Manager;
        }

        public void Attach(InstanceContext owner)
        {
        }

        public void Detach(InstanceContext owner)
        {
        }
    }
    public class ESBAPIManager { }
    public class PSRestServiceHost : ServiceHost
    {
        public PSRestServiceHost(Type t, Uri[] addresses)
            : base(t, addresses)
        {
            Logger.Log("PSRestServiceHost constructor");
        }
    }
    public class PSRestServiceFactory : ServiceHostFactoryBase
    {
        public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string service, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            // The service parameter is ignored here because we know our service. 
            PSRestServiceHost serviceHost = new PSRestServiceHost(typeof(PSRestService), baseAddresses);

            var endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IPSRestService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

            serviceHost.Opening += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Opening);
            serviceHost.Opened += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Opened);
            serviceHost.Closing += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Closing);
            serviceHost.Closed += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Closed);
            serviceHost.Faulted += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Faulted);
            serviceHost.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived);

            return serviceHost;
        }

        void serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived(object sender, UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("Unknown Message Received");
        }

        void serviceHost_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service faulted");
        }

        void serviceHost_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service closed");
        }

        void serviceHost_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service closing by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
        }

        void serviceHost_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service opened by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
        }

        void serviceHost_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.Log("service opening by sender: {0}", sender.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPSRestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "blockActivityTrans", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        transAckResponseData PostBlockActivity(blockActivityData blockactivitydata);
    }
    [ESBAPICreation]
    public class PSRestService : IPSRestService
    {
        public transAckResponseData PostBlockActivity(blockActivityData blockactivitydata)
        {
            return new transAckResponseData { Logs = Logger.GetCurrentLog() };
        }
    }
    public class blockActivityData { }
    public class transAckResponseData
    {
        public string Logs { get; set; }
    }
    public static class Logger
    {
        static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        public static void Log(string text, params object[] args)
        {
            if (args != null && args.Length > 0) text = string.Format(text, args);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            sb.AppendLine(text);
        }
        public static string GetCurrentLog()
        {
            string result = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**File: TestPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Quick template</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function StackOverflow_10721469_Test() {
            var url = "/StackOverflow_10721469.svc/blockActivityTrans";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: "{}",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $("#result").text(data.Logs);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#result").text("error");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="StackOverflow 10721469" onclick="StackOverflow_10721469_Test();" /> <br />
    <div id='result'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @carlosfigueira. I've been slammed at work and is a week away from a 2 weeks vacation. I'll get to this as soon as I can next week.

Comment: I was able to get the method to execute. Not sure why it wouldn't before. Since you took the time to test it and provide information, I'll reward you the answer and bounty. Thanks for taking the time. I'm still confused of why it was the case, but it works, and I'm just happy about that :)